# Is it possible to set up the database connection if we are provided with ODBC registry file?

Tags: sql-server, odbc, db2, database-connection

One of the users already has all the OBDC connections configured on to the RDC user account. That machine is used to connect to all the databases.

A new user on boards into the organization, his log in account is created on the same machine. This time the new user is being provided with an ODBC reg file, the ODBC reg file is an export from the initial user.

The ODBC file contains connection details about Teradata, SQL Server and DB2 databases. All the drivers required to connect to these databases are available for all the users who ever logs into the machine.

How can the new user use this ODBC reg file and configure all the connections in order to connect to the above 3 types of databases?

Comment: Importing the registry file should work.

Comment: I was unable to find any leads regarding how to import ODBC registry file. Is it possible if you can point me in the correct direction.

Comment: Double-click the registry file and follow the prompts.